# Applying a long list of labels in a factor in R

Tags: r, label

Usually, when I want to label a factor, I use the `apply_labels` function from `expss` and I add manually all labels, like this :

```r
apply_labels(df,
                var1=c("label1"=1,"label2"=2,"label3"=3),
                var2=c("label4"=1,...),
                ...)
```

But in my current case, I have an unlabellised factor `df$PAVEUN` that have 417 possible values. On another table (`df2`), I have all unique values with corresponding label (`df2$ENGLISH`). An overview of this dataframe is the following:

```r
> head(df2)
  CODE                                            ENGLISH
1    1                                           Managers
2   11 Chief executives, senior officials and legislators
3  111                   Legislators and senior officials
4 1111                                        Legislators
5 1112                        Senior government officials
6 1113            Traditional chiefs and heads of village
```

How can I label `df$PAVEUN` with `df2$ENGLISH` without having to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For labelled variables the code below should do the trick:

```
apply_labels(df,
                paven=setNames(df2$CODE, df2$ENGLISH),

                ...)
```

Generally speaking, labelled variables and factors are different things.   Code for factors will look like this:

```
df$paven_factor = factor(df$paven, levels = df2$CODE, labels = df2$ENGLISH)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `levels(df$PAVEUN) <- df2$ENGLISH)` will do what you want. However, it's up to you to make sure that the order of the levels corresponds correctly ... if the values of `df2$CODE` match the values in `df$PAVEUN` you might want to use `merge()` (from base R) or one of the `*_join()` functions from tidyverse to be more careful.